# facebook customer chat SDK with vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2

I just want to implement a Facebook customer chat feature with my `vuejs` application.
This is my full code in the `index.html` file.

```
 <body>
    <div id="app" page_id="PAGE_ID" minimized="false" class="fb-customerchat"></div>

    <!-- Include after Vue (before closing body) -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-fullpage.js/dist/vue-fullpage.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : 'APP_ID',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v2.11'
        });
      };
    (function(d, s, id){
      console.log('d',d,'s',s,'id',d)
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
```

I am sure that my `page_id` and `app_id` is correct.
I don't know what's wrong with the code. I can't see any error in the console log also.

I implement exact same thing in a normal html file. It works 100%

```
<body>
    <div
      class="fb-customerchat"
      page_id="PAGE_ID"
      minimized="false"
    ></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
          appId: 'APP_ID',
          autoLogAppEvents: true,
          xfbml: true,
          version: 'v2.11',
        });
      };
      (function (d, s, id) {
        var js,
          fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
          return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      })(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
    </script>
  </body>
```

I don't know why this is not working with the vue.js.

Is that something with `webpack` building or something else?

Comment: `this is not working` - do you get errors in the browser console? please describe how it's "not working" a little more

Comment: @JaromandaX No errors at console and nothing is displayed regrading to the fb chat.